# How socket and express listen on same port

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, socket.io, protocols

Hello I have a conceptional dellema.

I wanted to integrated socket.io(real-time communication) after user asks for drive(making an Uber like project).

I got an example here: [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@raj_36650/integrate-socket-io-with-node-js-express-2292ca13d891) Now as I can see express and socket are listening to the same port. How it can be possible?

Like if I send an http protocol request the app in express picks it up and does the job for me on port 80(say). Now I emit an event. It reaches port 80. How it decides that this goes to socket.io and not to app. On the server there is only 1 port 80. How on the same port, two different protocols are able to understand which request to process.

What my life looks like:
Client opened a random port and send a get request to the server. It is a protocol where data is designed in a particular format. Like header, body etc. Server picks it up and app in express decompiled it for me. Now client wants to open real time communication. He sends a request to open socket. All good. A request is received and socket opened.

Exactly here my life stops. How? How the socket starts to listen on the same port on my server and client? How server processes the request?

I am not able to get the feel of the real time communication with http protocol or any other protocol.

Like if I want to make my socket secure(I mean a particular socket used by particular authenticated user) I do something like:

```
app.post('/secure', jwt.verify, (req, res) => { });
```

Now let's say this request is responsible to open a socket connection for sharing of location data like in Uber. Now if I open a socket inside this then it will automatically be secure? Coming from a secure port? What the socket be like?

Please someone get me a feel of what is going on the server side and client side. I just don't understand it even after reading a lot on stack overflow.

There is a server and client may need to open real time communication after some time but how everything fits in?